# Looking for an idiom meaning "this is not relevant to you"

Tags: verbs, idioms

I'm looking for an idiom which is the opposite of "falls under your umbrella" or "up your ally".

For example:

> I noticed you are the head of IT at ACME. Until recently, I would have thought that reducing manufacturing cost operations is _____ [idiom for "not relevant for a person at your position"].

Comment: Someone else's problem? (SEP)

Comment: A rather old-fashioned British expression - _not your pigeon_.

Comment: "up your all***e***y". Your version sounds somewhat uncomfortable for your friend!

Comment: Could you tell us who is saying this to whom and in what context? An example sentence would be very useful.

Comment: @Greybeard for example : Noticed you are the head of IT at ACME. Until recently, I would have think that reducing manufacturing cost operations is _____[ idiom for "not relevant for a person at your position"].

Comment: _Not in your job description_ is a common expression, used ironically, but whether or not it would suit the OP's needs would depend on the context. More context is really necessary to answer this question.

Comment: @Dave Thanks *I would have **thought** that reducing **operational manufacturing** costs **wasn't** your line.* (A line = the goods or services that are produced/sold - hence, area of responsibility/interest.)

Comment: As an opening, it focuses too much on the sender, and it’s way too wordy. Instead, how about this? **The relationship between IT and manufacturing has been changing. I have something here that might interest you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could negate the idioms you provided in the question: "doesn't fall under your umbrella", "not up your alley". Many idiomatic responses would be prefaced with a negation:

- They don't enjoy it: "not your cup of tea"
- They haven't seen it before: "not your area of expertise," "not your wheelhouse"
- It's beyond them: "out of your depth", "over your head", "beyond you" (*note:* even if meant neutrally these will generally sound condescending)
- It's something that they don't (or shouldn't, or don't want to be forced to) have responsibility over: "above your pay grade"
- Tangentially referencing a related subject that they don't know about or aren't interested in: "But that's a whole different kettle of fish"

Comment: 'Above your pay grade' is the ideal solution for the example OP gives.